# get file name from file upload using jquery and set filename to a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, jsp

I have to get filename of the uploaded file and set it to the textfield

I have done as follows

```
<input type="file" name = "filename" id="upload">
<input type="text" name = "file" id="file">
```

//jquery

```
$('#upload').change(function() {
    var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    $('#file').val(filename);
});
```

and also tried this

```
$('#upload').change(function() {
    var filename = $(this).val();
    var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    }
    $('#file').val(filename);
});
```

but filename is not displayed in the textfield.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: filename is not displayed in the textfield

Comment: works fine for me http://jsbin.com/yuyuriqevi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: but not for me. Is there is anything wrong?

Comment: @Rohin check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to be using jquery inside document ready. You might have forgotten to add that. Here is the working code.

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#upload').change(function() {
       var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
      console.log(filename,$('#file'));
        var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");   
        $('#file').val(filename);
    });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name = "filename" id="upload">
                                <input type="text" name = "file" id="file">
```

Comment: This is an answer. But for me, it works when i placed the script at the end of the body tag